# In Bigquery How iterate the records as per counter in the table

Tags: google-bigquery

If we have input table is like this.

INPUT ::

| Parent | child | counter |
| --- | --- | --- |
| raju | naveen | 1 |
| raju | ravi | 2 |
| raju | ram | 3 |

i need a query to get the output in this format in Bigquery

OUTPUT ::

| header 1 | header 2 |
| --- | --- |
| raju | naveen |
| raju | ravi |
| raju | ravi |
| raju | ram |
| raju | ram |
| raju | ram |

i need Biquery query to get this.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use below.

```sql
SELECT parent, child FROM `input`, UNNEST(GENERATE_ARRAY(1, counter));

-- Query Results
+--------+--------+
| parent | child  |
+--------+--------+
| raju   | naveen |
| raju   | ravi   |
| raju   | ravi   |
| raju   | ram    |
| raju   | ram    |
| raju   | ram    |
+--------+--------+
```